# Using filter when 2 properties need evaluation for uniqueness

Tags: javascript

I have seen plenty of excellent examples of where you can use filter to remove duplicates from an array when only one property needs evaluated to determine uniqueness.

I have the function that I call to create an object:

```
        function fullTableObject(TableName, AuditAction, RowNumber) {
            this.TableName;
            this.AuditAction;
            this.RowNumber;
        }
```

I then loop through multiple result sets to build an array of the object above, like so:

```
var allTables = [];

for (var i = 0; i < tableNameArray.length; i++) {
    var oTable = new fullTableObject();
    oTable.TableName = tableNameArray[i];
    oTable.AuditAction = auditActionArray[i];
    oTable.TableRowNumber = i;
    allTables.push(oTable);
}
```

My question is how do I eliminate duplicates based on 2 properties?  For instance I may have 2 objects in the array where the TableName property set to "MYFIRSTTABLE", the the value of the AuditAction would be "UPDATE" and "INSERT" thus making these objects unique, which is ok.

The instance I am trying to account for is for 2 or more cases TableName set to "MYSECONDTABLE" and each AuditAction is set to "UPDATE".  Can filter be used to account for 2 properties in this approach?

Comment: Use a boolean AND to combine the two constraints "TableName is the same" and "AuditAction is the same" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example shows you how you can use the common reusable [uniqueBy](https://lodash.com/docs/#uniqBy) function with tuples as keys. The idea is to have a comparable representation of the keys (which are now pairs of values), for example a json string.

```js
var tableNameArray = ['TableA', 'TableB', 'TableA'];
var auditActionArray = ['ActionA', 'ActionA', 'ActionA'];

var allTables = [];
for (var i = 0; i < tableNameArray.length; i++) {
    var oTable = new FullTableObject(tableNameArray[i], auditActionArray[i], i);
    allTables.push(oTable);
}

// Having proper utilites makes this task a single call
allTables = uniqueBy(allTables, x => JSON.stringify([x.tableName, x.auditAction]));
console.log(allTables);

// Class names are usually capitalized, field names are camel case
function FullTableObject(tableName, auditAction, rowNumber) {
    this.tableName = tableName;
    this.auditAction = auditAction;
    this.rowNumber = rowNumber;
}

// This function is reusable, doesn't have any knowledge about tables and audits. Basically the same as lodash's _.uniqBy
function uniqueBy(array, keyFn) {
    var keys = new Set();
    var result = [];
    array.forEach(function(item) {
        var key = keyFn(item);
        if (!keys.has(key)) {
            keys.add(key);
            result.push(item);
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

Comment: When I try to plug this in, I am getting an error on this line allTables = uniqueBy(allTables, x => JSON.stringify([x.tableName, x.auditAction]));  What level of JS do you need to be running for this to work?

Comment: It is ECMAScript 2015. You can replace the lambda expression by `function(x) { return JSON.stringify([x.tableName, x.auditAction]); }` if you need to.

Comment: @MisterPositive But you might have problems with `Set` as well, that's ES2015 too I believe

Comment: That did the trick.  No issue with the Set, only the lambda.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to keep track on the unique `TableName`'s and `AuditAction`'s:

```
var allTables = [];
var uniqueTableNames = new Set();
var uniqueAuditActions = new Set();

for (var i = 0; i < tableNameArray.length; i++) {
    var oTable = new fullTableObject();
    oTable.TableName = tableNameArray[i];
    oTable.AuditAction = auditActionArray[i];
    oTable.TableRowNumber = i;

    if (uniqueTableNames.has(oTable.TableName) && 
        uniqueAuditActions.has(oTable.AuditAction)) continue;

    allTables.push(oTable);
    uniqueTableNames.add(oTable.TableName);
    uniqueAuditActions.add(oTable.AuditAction);
}
```

The `has` function of `Set` is more efficient than `indexOf` of `Array`, because it use a Hash Map internally, so we have O(1) agains O(n).

Comment: This approach did not work.  I am still getting multiple objects with the same TableName and AuditAction properties.

Comment: I tried you updated code, and it still did not work.

Comment: For example I have TABLENAME1 | UPDATE and TABLENAME1 | INSERT and its removing one of those when it should not.

Comment: That's really weird. I tested that code and worked fine

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the question well, but what about just simply concatenate these two properties to test uniqueness?

Your code would be like:

```
var allTables = [];
var uniqProps = [];

for (var i = 0; i < tableNameArray.length; i++) {
    var oTable = new fullTableObject();
    oTable.TableName = tableNameArray[i];
    oTable.AuditAction = auditActionArray[i];
    oTable.TableRowNumber = i;
    var uniqProp = oTable.TableName + '#' + oTable.AuditAction;
    if(uniqProps.indexOf(uniqProp) < 0) { //test if we already have the properties in double
        uniqProps.push(uniqProp);
        allTables.push(oTable);
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked well for me in solving my issue.  Simple and effective.

Comment: This will fail if there are two tables,
 for example `{TableName:'User',AuditAction:'PermissionGrant'}` and `{TableName:'UserPermission', AuditAction:'Grant'}`. I suggest using at least a separator character.

Comment: ! added a character separator to account for this @TamasHegedus.  Much Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this after your for-loop:

```
const allUniqueTables = allTables.reduce((res, curr) => {
                            if(res.length){
                                const isDuplicate = res.some((t) => (t.TableName === curr.TableName) 
                                                                    && (t.AuditAction == curr.AuditAction));
                                if(!isDuplicate){
                                    res.push(curr);
                                }
                            } else {
                                res.push(curr);
                            }
                            return res;
                        }, []);
```